# Is it possible to use Widevine DRM for protecting ePubs and Magazines?

Tags: android, ios, drm

What is the best total solution for protecting reading material like ePubs and magazines on multiple platforms, esp Android, iOS and Windows.

Is it possible to use Widevine DRM?